# Como faço para mudar o cabeçalho do csv, C#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, header

Estou gerando um arquivo CSV, mas gostaria que o *header* fosse igual ao *anottation displayName*. Quando exporto, o *displayName* é ignorado.

chamada do método

```
string csv = ListToCSV(resultado);
private string ListToCSV<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sList = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            Type type = typeof(T);
            var props = type.GetProperties();
            sList.Append(string.Join(";", props.Select(p => p.Name)));            

            sList.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            foreach (var element in list)
            {
                sList.Append(string.Join(";", props.Select(p => p.GetValue(element, null))));
                sList.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }

            return sList.ToString();
        }

File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "consulta.csv");
```

Comment: pode mostrar o código que você está usando pra gerar o csv?

Comment: posso sim. vou postar abaixo

Comment: @RicardoSoares edite a pergunta com o código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, gostaria de lembrar que montar um CSV corretamente não é tão simples quanto parece, então aconselho que utilize o [`CsvHelper`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper)

quanto ao DisplayName, você pode verificar se a Property possui este atributo utilizando o método [`PropertyIjnfo.GetCustomAttribute<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292(v=vs.110).aspx). Segue um exemplo.:

```
public class Exemplo
{
    [Display(Name = "Property 01")]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Property 02")]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Property 02")]
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

var props = typeof(Exemplo).GetProperties().Select(prop => {
    var display = prop.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
    if (display != null)
        return display.Name;
    return prop.Name;
});
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", props));
```

Dependendo da sua versão do .NET, talvez terá de fazer uso do método [`PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getcustomattributes(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var props = typeof(Exemplo).GetProperties().Select(prop => {
    var attributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0) {
        var display = attributes[0] as DisplayAttribute;
        return display.Name;
    }   
    return prop.Name
});
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", props));
```

Segue o exemplo utilizando o [`CsvHelper`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper).:

```
public class Exemplo
{
    [Display(Name = "Property 01")]
    public Guid Prop1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Property 02")]
    public Guid Prop2 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Property 03")]
    public Guid Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class ExemploMap : ClassMap<Exemplo>
{
    public ExemploMap()
    {
        var type = typeof(Exemplo);
        var props = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var display = prop.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
            Map(type, prop).Name(display?.Name ?? prop.Name);
        }
    }
}

var itens = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Select(i => new Exemplo
{
    Prop1 = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Prop2 = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Prop3 = Guid.NewGuid(),
});
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, Int16.MaxValue, true))
    {
        var csvWriter = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer);
        csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ExemploMap>();
        csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(itens);
        csvWriter.Flush();
    }

    File(stream, "text/csv", "consulta.csv")
}
```

Comment: muitíssimo obrigado. resolveu, abs